# google.script.run breaks $(document).ready or $(':checkbox').change(evaluateCheckbox);

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script

When I run google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildCheckboxes).withFailureHandler(fail).getNumber(); it breaks $(document).ready or $(':checkbox').change(evaluateCheckbox); (not sure which is not working).  But if I directly access run buildCheckboxes() the $(document).ready & .change continues to work as expected.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//buildCheckboxes(); 
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildCheckboxes).withFailureHandler(fail).getNumber(); 
 $(':checkbox').change(evaluateCheckbox);
});

 function buildCheckboxes(num){
if (!num){ var num=3;}
$("#checkboxes").empty();
for (var i=0;i<3;i++){
$("#checkboxes").append('<input type="checkbox" name="cb_'+i+'" value="v2" >Checkbox '+i+'<br><input type="button" id="cb_'+i+'" value="Button"><br>');
$(":button").hide();
 }
 }

 function evaluateCheckbox(){
     if (this.checked) {
       $("#"+this.name).show();
     } else {
       $("#"+this.name).hide();
     } 
 }
```

Comment: Seems you are missing to delegate. $("#checkboxes").on("change",":checkbox",evaluateCheckbox)

Comment: I didn't have a problem with the change.  The issue I was having was that when I used google.script.run to access the .cs file and then returned to the html file it breaks the event listener that was launched during ready.    I figured out to move the .change to the returned function and it worked out again.    I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it figured out.  I had to move  $(':checkbox').change(evaluateCheckbox); from the document.ready to the function that gets ran after the script returns from the .cs file.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//buildCheckboxes(); 
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildCheckboxes).withFailureHandler(fail).getNumber(); 

});

 function buildCheckboxes(num){
if (!num){ var num=3;}
$("#checkboxes").empty();
for (var i=0;i<3;i++){
$("#checkboxes").append('<input type="checkbox" name="cb_'+i+'" value="v2" >Checkbox '+i+'<br><input type="button" id="cb_'+i+'" value="Button"><br>');
$(":button").hide();
 }
 $(':checkbox').change(evaluateCheckbox);  //Move this here to make it work.
 }

 function evaluateCheckbox(){
     if (this.checked) {
       $("#"+this.name).show();
     } else {
       $("#"+this.name).hide();
     } 
 }
```

Comment: Same result as delegating to a container in .ready - recommended method. If you add more checkboxes later you might add event handlers again and again to existing checkboxes. Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but may have not put it in the correct place.   I replaced the line  $(':checkbox').change(evaluateCheckbox); with $("#checkboxes").on("change",":checkbox",evaluateCheckbox) and nothing happened.

Comment: mplungjan, the problem I was having was that leaving the html file using google.script.run seems to break the .ready and I needed to rerun the change listener in the return function.